# evaluation of integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-b\sqrt{x^{2}+a}}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I need to find the analytical expression of the following integral when $a,b > 0$:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-b\sqrt{x^{2}+a}}dx.$$

Can someone help me here?

Comment: You say you need it, but you should be prepared for the possibility that an analytic expression cannot be found.

Answer (score 2):

First write the integral as

$$2 \int_0^{\infty} dx \, e^{-b \sqrt{x^2+a}}$$

then sub $x=\sqrt{a} \sinh{t}$, $dx = \sqrt{a} \cosh{t} dt$, to get

$$2 \sqrt{a} \int_0^{\infty} dt \, \cosh{t} \, e^{-b \sqrt{a} \cosh{t}}$$

which is expressible in terms of a [modified Bessel function of the second kind](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32):

$$2 \sqrt{a} K_1\left (b \sqrt{a} \right )$$

Comment: Well, so my comment above proved too pessimistic. Excellent.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen: helps to know this off the top of your head.  Why I do, yet I cannot locate my car keys, don't ask.